# Conjugation of malen

Tags: conjugation

I was looking at the translation for the recent German song "Je ne parle pas francais" and one of the constructions seemed to go against what I had learned:

```
Und male zwei Tassen Kaffee      |  And you paint two cups of coffee
Mit 'nem Stift auf deine Hand    |  With the pen in your hand
```

The verb `malen` here is conjugated to `male` which, as I have learned, is used with the `ich` form.. That is `Ich male.`

However, the translation suggests that is in the `du` form, as it says "**you** paint two cups of coffee"

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The translation is wrong.

The correct translation is:

> And [I] paint two cups of coffee
>   With a pen **onto** your hand

(auf=*onto*, not *in*)

So first person is correct.

Comment: Warum nicht Imperativ?

Comment: Without context it could be imperative but the previous line (which can be googled easily) is "Ich find's irgendwie charmant".